# Android viewFlipper causing NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-layout, nullpointerexception

In my android apps i have 2 Layouts created using viewFlipper

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <ViewFlipper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:id="@+id/switching"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

          <include layout="@layout/activity_login"/>
          <include layout="@layout/content_team_choose"/>
          <include layout="@layout/waiting"/>
  </ViewFlipper>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ViewFlipper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/switch_game"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/main_game"/>
    <include layout="@layout/chat"/>
</ViewFlipper>
```

in my fist activity have access to the view like this

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.switching );
        viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.switching);

//some other code which triggers the change of the view,
//like a onClickListener

                    viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(1);
```

and this works fine. In my second activity, if i try to access to the other view flipper, and i do vievFlipper.setDisplayedChild(1) a NullPointerExcption is thrown. So i tried this

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.switch_game);
    viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.switch_game);
  if(viewFipper == null) 
        Log.d("ViewError", "the viewFlipper is null");
```

and the Log appears, but i can't get why only in this case the view is null.
I have even tryied to get the Layout "switching" in the second activity and this too gave me the same issues.

EDIT. The NullPointerException was thrown by a viewFlipper.setDisplayedChild(1);
trying to access to a children of the layout, but i wasn't sure if only the childrens were null or all the viewFlipper, so i tryied the last part of code, verifying that the whole layout was null

Comment: Please check the layout for setContentView is it the correct one R.layout.main_game

Comment: i haven't noticed the inconsistency between the first and second code, but i've tryied to substitute "R.layout.main_game" with "R.layout.switch_game);" and nothing canged

Answer (score 2):

> NullPointerException is thrown when an application attempts to use an
>   object reference that has the null value.

A **[ViewFlipper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html)** is mainly used in cases when we need to transform one view into another.

```
  viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.switch_game);
```

Comment: yes, sorry i have made a bit of confusion in the last part.
The NullPointerException was thrown trying to access to a children of the layout, but i wasn't sure if only the childrens were null or all the viewFlipper, so i tryied the last part of code, verifying that the whole layout was null